# Multiple price groups per user per product: how to minimize amount of queries?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following structures in my Rails (4.2) e-commerce application:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :prices

  def best_price(price_groups)
    prices.where(price_group_id: price_groups).minimum(:value)
  end

  def default_price
    prices.where(price_group_id: 1).first.value
  end

end

class Price < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :price_group
  belongs_to :product
end


class PriceGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  has_many :prices
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :price_groups
end
```

Many users can be members of many price groups with many product price rows in each of them.
There is a default group with default prices for each product plus there can be many optional price groups with special (reduced) product prices for some users.
The problem is - this way I'm getting two queries per each product listed in my index page:

```
SELECT MIN("prices"."value") FROM "prices" WHERE "prices"."product_id" = $1 AND "prices"."price_group_id" IN (1, 2)  [["product_id", 3]]
```

and

```
SELECT  "prices".* FROM "prices" WHERE "prices"."product_id" = $1 AND "prices"."price_group_id" = $2  ORDER BY "prices"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["product_id", 3], ["price_group_id", 1]]
```

So, here is my question: 
Is there some (easy) way to load everything at once? Like getting list of product objects with default and minimum price fields.
I understand how it can be done in a single SQL query, but I can't think of anything more natural, rails-activerecord-way.

**** Upd:
I ended up with

```
# I'm using Kaminari pagination

@products = Product.page(params[:page]).per(6)

product_ids = @products.map(&:id)

@best_prices=Price.where(product_id: product_ids, price_group_id: @user_price_groups).group(:product_id).minimum(:value)

@default_prices=Price.where(product_id: product_ids, price_group_id: 1).group(:product_id).minimum(:value)
```

These group queries produce hashes like `{ product_id => value }, ...` so all I need is just using `@best_prices[product.id]` and so on in my views.

Thanks to everyone!

Comment: I don't think there's an easy way without a custom sql query (which could probably be expressed with arel rather than as just a blob of sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @Frederick Cheung, and I don't like a custom sql query, and I am not  familiar with arel, so my solution will be:

```
products = Product.limit(10)
product_ids = products.map(&:id)

products_hash = products.reduce({}) do |hash, product|
    hash[price.id] = {product: product} } 
    hash
end

best_prices = Price.select("MIN(value) AS min_price, product_id")
    .where(product_id: product_ids, price_group_id: price_groups)
    .group("product_id")
    .reduce({}) do |hash, price|
        hash[price.product_id] = { best_price: price.min_price }
        hash
end

default_prices = Price.where(price_group_id: 1, product_id: product_ids)
    .reduce({}) do |hash, price|
        hash[price.product_id] = {default_price: price.value }
        hash
end

# A hash like {
#  1: {product: <Product ...>, best_price: 12, default_price: 11},
#  2: {product: <Product ...>, best_price: 12, default_price: 11},
#  3: {product: <Product ...>, best_price: 12, default_price: 11}
# }
result = products_hash.deep_merge(best_prices).deep_merge(default_prices)
```

Still, three quests will be needed, not only one, but this solved the N+1 problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a default scope and includes prices and your problem will be solved

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope { includes(:prices) }
  has_many :prices

 def best_price(price_groups)
   prices.where(price_group_id: price_groups).minimum(:value)
 end

 def default_price
  prices.where(price_group_id: 1).first.value
 end
end
```

Comment: Nothing changed, but now I'm getting 1400 ms instead of 300 ms per page query -)

Comment: try Product.eager_load(:prices).where(price_group_id: price_groups).minimum(:value)